# Copy And Paste Data Matching

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have FileA with raw data. The blue cells are headers, labelled A-J. The peach colored cells represent the data, which is typically text that varies and is not constant and are labelled 1-10.

File A:

[image]

File B:

[image]
The second sheet contains the headers in blue as described above.

I have been unable to write a vba code to match the specified header to a column and paste the subsequent data below in the next available cell.
I.e. (A1,A5,A8,A11,A14,A17 are matched to their respective header and pasted into the second sheet in A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)

You'll notice that in the raw data it is not completely constant, Rows 4-5, 10-12, 13-14 are missing data for column F making it harder to match in a large data set.

the current code that come close to helping but doesnt work is posted below:

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = wbk.Sheets(2)
Dim cell As Range
Dim refcell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws.Select

    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:Z1")

        cell.Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Copy

        For Each refcell In ws2.Range("A1:Z1")
            If refcell.Value = cell.Value Then refcell.Paste
        Next refcell

    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Addition:

```
    Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)
Set WS2 = wbk.Sheets(2)
Dim cell As Range
Dim refcell As Range
Dim Col As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws.Select

    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:Z15000")

        cell.Activate
        Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("Cell").Value.Rows("1:1"), False)

        For Each refcell In WS2.Range("A1:Z1")
            Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Value = Rng.Value
        Next refcell

    Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Where does the code go wrong? How isn't it working? It may help to step through the code with `F8` and see where the loop misses some info.

Comment: Alright so I tried the code added the the bottom of the page to select a cell  below the title line and copy it but it ends up with a run time error.

It might be best to ignore the code i have if its confusing and for me to simple ask if you have seen any code anywhere that will help sorting through a situation like the one i described.

Comment: In essence, I have a raw data sheet with data labelled 1-10 (which vary) and columns (that are fixed) labelled A-J. I need select both for example A1:A2 and match the A1 value within the range Sheet2'A1:J1 (Obviously Column A) and then paste the second value we selected (A2) to the bottom of the respective matched column.

Example:

Sheet 1 G10:G11 ----> G10 value is matched to sheet 2's values ranging from A1:J1 and is matched to cell H1 and the value in G11 is pasted in the last empty cell in column H.

Comment: Another example:
Sheet 1 H7:H8 ----> H7 value is matched to sheet 2's values ranging from A1:J1 and is matched to cell H1 and the value in H8 is pasted in the last empty cell in column H.

Comment: I'm little confused, are copying FileA data to FileB?

Comment: you may want to post examples

Comment: Can we assume that between header-value block are always one row breaks? And that in header-value block there is always one header row - one value row connection? Or can we have for example 2 value rows for some header rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can go the other way around:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim hedaerCell As Range
    Dim labelsArray As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet02") '<--| reference your "headers" worksheet
        For Each hedaerCell In .Range("A1:J1") '<--| loop through all "headers"
            labelsArray = GetValues(hedaerCell.value) '<--| fill array with all labels found under current "header"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, hedaerCell.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(labelsArray)).value = Application.Transpose(labelsArray) '<--| write down array values from current header cell column first not empty cell
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetValues(header As String) As Variant
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iFound As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet01").UsedRange '<--| reference your "data" worksheet
        ReDim labelsArray(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, header)) As Variant '<--| size an array to store as many "labels" as passed 'header' occurrences
        Set f = .Find(what:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| start seraching for passed 'header'
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = f.Address
            Do
                iFound = iFound + 1
                labelsArray(iFound) = f.Offset(1)
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
    GetValues = labelsArray
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Do you know why there would be a run time error 13, type mismatch?

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, hedaerCell.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(labelsArray)).Value = Application.Transpose(labelsArray)